# RestKit and non-lightweight core data migration with mapping model and NSEntityMigrationPolicy possible?

Tags: core-data, restkit, core-data-migration

I'm inheriting the support of an existing iOS app using RestKit, and I'm new to RestKit. I've performed several complex core data migrations in the past, using model versions, mapping models and entity migration policies.

Now I'm wondering how this can be achieved when RestKit is in use. The way the code is currently structured, there is a call to:

```
BOOL migrationSucceeded = [RKManagedObjectStore migratePersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                       atURL:storeURL
                                                                toModelAtURL:modelURL
                                                                       error:&error
                                                  configuringModelsWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectModel *model, NSURL *sourceURL) {

    CLS_LOG(@"Model version %@", [model versionIdentifiers]);

    // Examine each model and configure search indexing appropriately based on the versionIdentifiers configured in the model
    if ([[model versionIdentifiers] isEqualToSet:[NSSet setWithObject:@"2.0"]]
        || [[model versionIdentifiers] isEqualToSet:[NSSet setWithObject:@"2.1"]]
        || [[model versionIdentifiers] isEqualToSet:[NSSet setWithObject:@"2.2"]]
        || [[model versionIdentifiers] isEqualToSet:[NSSet setWithObject:@"2.3"]]) {

        NSEntityDescription *productFamilyEntity = [[model entitiesByName] objectForKey:kEntityNameProductFamily];
        [RKSearchIndexer addSearchIndexingToEntity:productFamilyEntity onAttributes:@[@"descEn", @"descFr"]];
    }

}];
```

Followed by a call to:

```
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath
                                                                 fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil
                                                                      withConfiguration:nil
                                                                                options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES,
                                                                                          NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}
                                                                                  error:&error];
```

From what I can see, the core data migration is performed in the call to `migratePersistentStoreOfType`..., which I think infers the mapping model instead of using the one I've created.

Later when `addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath` is called, the migration has already been performed.

How can I structure the code so that a custom mapping model specifying `NSEntityMigrationPolicies` will be used during the migration? Is this possible with RestKit?

Thanks in advance,

Philippe

Comment: Handle the migration yourself, or edit and submit a pull request factoring out the mapping model access so you can subclass to return or set mapping model URLs (ensuring it's backwards compatible)